# pygame sprites and pygame.display.flip() results in artifacts

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm programming a python Tetris clone for a university course. It works like charm, as long as I'm not trying to change the route of the falling blocks. When I speed them up or move the block left or right, I'm getting the artifacts, shown on the screenshot below.

The code is the same for every movement of the block:

```
runningBlock.update()
runningBlock.draw(field)
screen.blit(field, (20, 20))
pygame.display.flip()
```

while the update() method just sets the center of the moving object to a new position. screen is the gray area on the screenshot, field is the white playground on top of the grey screen. Any idea, what I'm missing in here?

BTW, frame rate is set to 30, shouldn't be the problem, should it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay got it. I just refilled the field before updating the blocks:

```
field.fill((255, 255, 255))
runningBlock.update()
runningBlock.draw(field)
lyingBlocks.draw(field)
screen.blit(field, (20, 20))
pygame.display.flip()
```